# html strikethrough with modal

Tags: html, modal-dialog, strikethrough

I have a html code that i'm trying to edit, but it seems like a theres some css with it but I want to make it so that on checked there's a strike through and when all checkboxes are complete a modal comes up that says congratulations on to the next step. I've include the html and a screenshot of what I'm talking about. Very novice at this stuff.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCBQRUJTL64Y[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfaBQ.jpg)

Comment: Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and reword this before you get a bunch of vote downs for a bad question. Too many bad questions and you won't be allowed to ask questions again for a while.  If needed also look at [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). ... in particular you need to include code here and change your title but you also have some other opportunities for improving the quality of the question. Remember we don't get paid. Make it easy for us to help. :)

Comment: I apologize I mentioned in the post that I’m a complete novice so not sure how to post questions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  if (!wlcl_site_url_post) {
    var wlcl_site_url_post = 'https://rachelwhynot.com';
  }
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h3 class='wlcl_title chk_title_8'>Action Items: Tracking Your Onboarding Process</h3>

<input class='item_chk shortcode_chk' id='item_chk_0' type='checkbox' name='item_chk[]' value='8-32-14' />
<label for='item_chk_0'><span class='item_name_8'>Watch Video Training</span></label>
```

Give this a shot. You can do some pretty cool things with CSS attribute selectors and different inputs.

You could also use jQuery to do this in a $(document).ready() function, but that's certainly not the only way to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks Dan thats great! Exactly what I'm looking for. Only problem when I copy the code and paste it doesn't work :/ It only works on here?

Comment: You might need to restructure your code a bit - I found it very verbose and some of the tags seemed pointless. If you look at my code above, you'll see that <input> and <label> are next to each other (sibling elements), which means that the CSS rule of "input[...] + label" will apply to them. If they're not sibling elements, you'd have to edit the CSS rule.

Comment: I'd recommend using the format that I've used above, and if you need to group multiple of these two elements together, do that with a <div> or <section> element.